Does the prisma global omit option affect the create method?
I have decided to use the prisma global omit method to remove the password field everytime i am querying the database for a user this way:
const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  omit: {
    user: { password: true },
  },
});

However I am worried that this might cause my creating and saving a user to the database to exclude the password field entirely since the omission was done globally. No reference to this was made in the doc. Please provide answer regarding this.
Has anyone tried this, and what was their result?

I just tested it. As expected it does not prevent the omitted field from being created or updated, only from being read.
